# In extjs textfield how can I change afterSubTpl dynamically?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am facing problem in dynamically changing `afterSubTpl` that I have used in textfield . 
Is there any way that I can change `afterSubTpl`

Comment: Please provide a minimal description and example of what you want to achieve. [see](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have a textfield in which I have applied afterSubTpl .And in it I am displaying a text in afterSubTpl .Aside of it I have a combo Now the html in subTpl should be dynamically change based on the value of combo.But I am unable to change the html content of afterSubTpl.So is theere any method to change it in extjs..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8gkhj47/2/)

Create element:

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  id: 'mytextfield',
  fieldLabel : 'Text',
  afterSubTpl: ['<div id="{id}-title" data-ref="title">afterSubTpl</div>'],
  childEls: ['title']


}
```

Select listener of combo box:

```
'select': function(cmb, selected) {
  var textField = Ext.getCmp('mytextfield');
  textField.title.setHtml('<div>new afterSubTpl' + selected.data.name + '</div>');
  textField.title.setStyle({color: "red"});   
}
```

It uses the  [childEls](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-childEls) logic to reference the HTML DOM Element which was created based on the afterSubTpl config.
Within the 'select' listener of the combo box the element which was added within the childEls is used to update the HTML content. This Ext.dom.Element can be manipulated according to [Sencha Doc](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element)